# Как правильно ответить на вопрос

Tags: алгоритм

Следующий код осмысленный? Пожалуйста, ответьте подробно.

```
REAL Y=2.0, X=1.0, E=1.0;
DO (E=E/2.0; Y=X+E;
) WHILE (Y<>1.0)
```

Comment: Запустил программу. Почему программа перестала считать через 30 итераций, хотя 1<>1 (е в степени)?

Comment: Язык программирования укажи.

Comment: Кто угадает язык по трём строкам? Fortran? Осмысленный - понятие относительное. Может надо проверить выполнится ли этот цикл хотя бы два раз. Достаточно посчитать вручную всего один раз. Если y получится = 1 с первого раза, то смысла в цикле заведомо нет. Другой вариант, это когда y всегда <> 1, получаем бесконечный цикл. E должен стремиться к нулю, значит y стремиться к 1. Достигнет ли он 1? Подскажет спец по вычислениям с реальными числами. Если скажет, что не достигнет, тогда вопрос в том, а есть ли для кого-то смысл в бесконечных циклах?

Comment: @Qwertiy, предположим, это неизвестный нам язык программирования, здесь это неважно, важен сам алгоритм. Теоретически, да он бесконечен,но в реалиях жизни в работе с железом получается иначе.

Comment: @V.Ch, я ж вроде написал ответ?

Answer (score 5):

Бинарное представление `y` содержит только два единичных бита: первый (целая часть равна 1) и ещё один, отдалённый от первого на некоторую степень двойки. Сначала это `1.1`, потом `1.01`, `1.001` и так далее. Теоретически - до бесконечности. Но в компьютере вещественные числа имеют ограниченную точность. Как только тот бит оказывается за пределами этой точности, получается число, равное `1`.

Замечу, что в этом коде все операции помимо сложения выполняются абсолютно точно.

---

Аналогичный код на джаваскрипте выполняет 53 итерации (это разрядность мантиссы double):

```
var y=2, x=1, e=1;

do {
  e /= 2;
  y = x + e;
} while (y !== 1);
```

Comment: а можно поподробнее про *Замечу, что в этом коде все операции помимо сложения выполняются абсолютно точно.* ? как тут с точностью деления, например?

Comment: @splash58, деление на 2 уменьшает значение экспоненты на 1. Все биты мантиссы 0. Поскольку выход из цикла произойдёт, когда число итераций превысит дину мантиссы, а деление станет неточным, когда закончатся все отрицательные значения экспоненты, а потом, когда бит в денормализованной форме проползёт всё число. Даже вне зависимости от размера экспоненты, денормализованное число позволит без потерь сохранить точное значение, которым мы увеличиваем единицу, но тут до этого не дойдёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за ответ, нормализация числа с плавающей точкой всему виной, как  понял.

Comment: @V.Ch, нет, неправильно. Нормализация не при чём.

Comment: @Qwertiy, количество итераций зависит от разрядности типа данных, верно?

Comment: @V.Ch, да. Равно числу бит в мантиссе.